# Not getting Redeem code entering option

Tags: samsung, in-app-purchase

I am using Samsung j7 and I want to make some purchases but I am unable to find Redeem code entering option there. I have Redeem code for purchase but the option is not there. Previously it was right there but now its gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## You won't find it there.

Where you **will** find it by doing this:

1. Open the play store.
2. Tap the Hamburger-three lines thing to open the side menu, and tap redeem.
3. Put in your Redeem Code
4. Enjoy your new google play credit!

Comment: @SyedaZunairah   Really? You can just redeem the code there, and switch payment method. If the code is for a very certain app (Like the one in the screenshot) Google Play will recognise it.

Comment: When you input the code (Via Play store) what Error comes up?

Comment: Either that, or your code does Not work. Where did you aquire it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46790/discussion-between-dan-brown-and-syeda-zunairah).

Comment: yeah,Google changed its settings and now you can only redeem from playstore. Thanks it helped